# Append to List Variable with Racket

Tags: list, scheme, append, racket

I want to add an integer to a list that already exists using Racket.
Here is the code that I have so far.

```
(define (countBlackPegs gameList playerList)
(define blackPegs '())

(if (equal? (car playerList) (car gameList)) 
  (set! blackPegs '(1))
;;otherwise
  (set! blackPegs '(0)))
)
```

In theory I should be able to repeat the if statement (examining a different part of the list each time) and then append the blackPegs list with the appropriate value based on the result of the if statement. Unfortunately every append function I have tried doesn't work correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to modify (using `set!`) a list that already exists, do something along these lines, for adding a new element at the beginning:

```
(set! blackPegs (cons 1 blackPegs))
```

Or for adding a new element at the end:

```
(set! blackPegs (append blackPegs (list 1)))
```

However, be warned that in Scheme this style of programming is not recommended, you should try to avoid mutating variables - a functional programming style is preferred.